# Deserialize Object Hierarchy in YAMLDotNet

Tags: yamldotnet

I am using YamlDotNet and it works pretty well. I have a quick question about serializing object trees though. For example, I have

```
class A {
   [YamlMember(Alias = "p1")]
   public string P1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to inherit from A like so:

```
class B : A {
   [YamlMember(Alias = "p2")]
   public string P2 { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, I created a document object like this:

```
class D {
   [YamlMember(Alias = "a")]
   public A InputA { get; set; }

   [YamlMember(Alias = "b")]
   public B InputB { get; set; }
}
```

I deserialized the following Yaml:

```
a:
  p1: foo
b:
  p1: foo
  p2: bar
```

Using the following code:

```
 var ds = new Deserializer();
 var d = ds.Deserialize<D>(reader);
```

Surprisingly, I found that:

```
 d.InputB.P1 == null
```

This will work fine in JSON (although I have only used Jackson in Java). Is this simply not supported or am I missing something?

Comment: Which version are you using? It works with the latest one (4.1.0): https://dotnetfiddle.net/e3h57C

Comment: Thank you @AntoineAubry. I am using YamlDotNet.NetCore version 1.0.0. Is that an older or unsupported version? My project targets .NET Core 1.0.

Comment: I don't know what package is that, nor who published it. The official NuGet package is YamlDotNet, and is compatible with .NET Core. You are encouraged to use it and report any issue on GitHub. Thanks

Comment: Sounds good! Will try the official package!

Comment: Hey @AntoineAubry, yes, this worked. For .NET core 1.0, I referenced YamlDotNet.Standard which worked. Thank you!

Comment: Just to be clear, the official package is [YamlDotNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/YamlDotNet) and not YamlDotNet.Standard.

Comment: Oh interesting. YamlDotNet definitely didnt work with .net core 1.0. I will recheck my configuration and post logs.

Comment: That's weird. Could you [open an issue here](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/issues) ? That would be a better place for this discussion.